# How to call those who have more data? json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Good day, as I can call from an array of a json those that contain more data, I am creating a graph and must contain those with more data, I have this code where I send my data

```
vehiculoPorColores = () => {
const _this = this
fetch("/live/graph/color")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(datos => {
    const vehicleKey = Object.keys(datos)
    console.log(vehicleKey)
    _this.setState(
      {
        vehiculosC: vehicleKey.splice(0, 5).map((i, e) => ({
          name: vehicleKey[e],
          colores: datos[i]
        }))
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)
      }
    )
  })
  }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "lavender": 3,
  "white": 12,
  "dimgrey": 4,
  "seagreen": 2,
  "lightslategrey": 6,
  "slategrey": 7,
  "indianred": 2,
  "snow": 1,
  "darkslategrey": 1,
  "khaki": 1,
  "gainsboro": 3,
  "palevioletred": 1,
  "darkgrey": 1
}
```

to be more specific: json

I need to sort the data and choose the 5 records with the highest values, right now I only send a call to 5 but they are not the ones that have more data, and I need that and that they are only 5, aahh and I work in react

Comment: What do you mean "those that have more data"? More data than what?

Comment: in the image a list is shown, this list has colors and numbers, those with higher numbers, I do not know if I understand? img= https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pXLp.png

Comment: Higher than what? "Higher" is a relative term. The code can't guess what you're using as a threshold to define "higher". You have to tell it what the threshold is.

Comment: Maybe you mean that you wish to sort the data and choose the 5 records with the highest values?

Comment: Exactly, I need to sort the data and choose the 5 records with the highest values, sorry I cannot specify, I almost do not speak english

Comment: Please show your JSON data in text format, not image.

Comment: is up, already as text @geoidesic

Comment: can you check please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an array in JS you can do...

Having an object shaped as:
{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
}

Then having an array:

```js
[{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
},
{
 key1: 20,
 key2: "a string"
}]
```

You can do this:

```
[{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
},
{
 key1: 20,
 key2: "a string"
}].sort((elemN, elemNplus)=> elemN.key1 - elemNplus.key1) :: output => [{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
},
{
 key1: 20,
 key2: "a string"
}]
```

and Greater first:

```js
[{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
},
{
 key1: 20,
 key2: "a string"
}].sort((elemN, elemNplus)=> elemNplus.key1 - elemN.key1) :: output => [{
 key1: 20,
 key2: "a string"
},
{
 key1: 10,
 key2: "a string"
}]
```